# How do I Set TextFields from ParseQueryAdapter?

Tags: android-fragments, parse-platform

I have a ParseQueryAdapter that is populating a listview inside of a fragment:

QueryAdapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

public CustomAdapter(Context context) {

    super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
        public ParseQuery create() {
            ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Invoice");
            query.whereEqualTo("CustomerID", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
            return query;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public View getItemView(ParseObject object, View cellview, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (cellview == null) {

        cellview = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.cell_layout, null);

    }

    TextView cellDate = (TextView) cellview.findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);
    TextView invoice = (TextView) cellview.findViewById(R.id.invoiceNoTextView);

    cellDate.setText(object.getString("Date"));
    invoice.setText(object.getString("InvoiceNumber"));

    return cellview;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

}
}
```

Fragment Containing Listview:

```
public class InvoiceHistory extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

final   FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_invoice_history, container, false);

    ListView invoicesListView = (ListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.invoiceList);

    ParseQueryAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity());
    invoicesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            Fragment detailView = new InvoicesFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.placeholder, detailView);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });

    invoicesListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.loadObjects();

    return layout;
}

}
```

This populates the ListView with the proper fields from the query, but when I click on one of the cells the fragment transaction takes place, but i can't figure out how to set textfields on that new fragment with ParseObject Keys from the Query.

This is the fragment that gets Presented that I want to set the Textfields in:

```
public class InvoicesFragment extends Fragment {


public InvoicesFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_invoices, container, false);


    return layout;
}
```

Android is super new to me so maybe this is a wrong way to approach it. But all i want to do here is have that detail fragment show up with populated TextViews. Im not really sure what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could approach this by setting up a constructor in your DetailsFragment that you can pass in the textview info you want to show. In the example below, the data and invoice number are passed into the constructor. When the fragment is set up, this fragment is set up with the Parse object's data:

```
invoicesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    ParseObject object = adapter.getItem(i);
    Fragment detailView = DetailsFragment.newInstance(object.getString("Date"),
                                                    object.getString("InvoiceNumber"));
    // ...
  }
});
```

Here's a portion of the DetailsFragment showing the new constructor as well as how you could use them in setting up your view:

```
// InvoicesFragment.java
public static class InvoicesFragment extends Fragment {

  // ...

  public static InvoicesFragment newInstance(String invoiceDate, String invoiceNumber) {
    InvoicesFragment f = new InvoicesFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("invoiceDate", InvoiceDate);
    args.putString("invoiceNumber", InvoiceNumber);
    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;
  }

  public String getInvoiceDate() {
    return getArguments().getString("invoiceDate", "");
  }

  public String getInvoiceNumber() {
    return getArguments().getString("invoiceNumber", "");
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_invoices, container, false);

    // Assign some TextView, ex: dateTextView
    dateTextView.setText(getInvoiceDate());
    return layout;
  }

}
```